# Heroku App + Heroku Postgres query doesn't seem to be working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, deployment, heroku-postgres

I have a React, Node/Express, Postgres app hosted / deployed on heroku
Everything was working locally up until I made configurations for deployment
The client side seems to be working, server side as well
Seems to have an issue with pool.query

Things I attempted:

1. heroku pg:info // returns table with my database info

Plan: Mini 
Status:Available
Connections: 0/20
PG Version: 14.6
Created: 2023-01-13 10:28 UTC
Data Size: 0 B/1.00 GB (Unknown)
Tables: 4
Rows: 0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback: Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on: postgresql-aerodynamic-45124

based on this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-connection-pooling), I expected to see expected to also see this included, but didn't:
Connection Pooling: Available

2. heroku addons --app [app-name] // returns:
   The table above shows add-ons and the attachments to the current app (app-name) or other apps.
3. heroku addons:info --app app-name heroku-postgresql // returns:

=== postgresql-aerodynamic-45124
Attachments:  new-nowww::DATABASE
Installed at: Fri Jan 13 2023 02:28:37 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Owning app:   app-name
Plan:         heroku-postgresql:mini
Price:        $5/month
State:        created

4. I included SSL connection according to this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-postgres):
   const proConfig = process.env.DATABASE_URL  + "?sslmode=require";
5. I just received an email from heroku with the following:
   Maintenance is required for your database

Your database DATABASE_URL on app-name requires maintenance. During this period, your database will become read-only. Once maintenance has completed, your database credentials and hostname will have changed, but we will update your app's config variables accordingly to reflect the new database connection string.

This automated maintenance is a necessary part of our Essenial-tier plans, Mini and Basic. Should you need more control over maintenance windows, a production database (Standard tier or higher) offers more control over database maintenance, as we are able to schedule them in advance and provide better tools for self-served maintenance.

We expect maintenance to last just a few moments depending on the size of your database. We will notify you when maintenance begins, and again once it's complete.

// I imagine this interferes with my app, but I first deployed 11 January (currently 15 January), so I don't understand what the issue might be. Though I found another post on SO about credentials changing, but my db should've worked prior to literally just right now when I received the email.

Link to my db.js setup:
https://github.com/AnthonyVNgo/nowww-app/blob/main/db.js